# Why do I suddenly get unkown error when try to log in through Civimobile?

Tags: civimobile

I used to be able to log in into my Joomla based CiviCRM with Civimobile, but last week I logged out on Android, and can't log back in. It finds the site, I think, but when typing in credentials it says "unknown error".
It might be some permission related problem but don't know where check and change these for Civimobile.
Turned off firewall, reinstalled both the app and the extension, didn't help.
I need help here I think.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to click "logout from mobile" under my contact summary page/mobile tab;-)
It recreated the API that started working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check resource URL in civicrm settings php? It might be because the civicrm path is not set correctly

Comment: Not sure what to look for in civicrm.settings.php. Extention path in civi admin is  [civicrm.files]/ext/ which is actually, https://mysite.com/media/civicrm/ext. (thats where civimobile is)This path I cant find in civicrm.settings.php, but all other extensions seem to be working.

Comment: I would/could use QR code login too, but QR code never appear anymore on my admin page. It used to appear before.

Comment: Sorry i meant resource url in UI

Comment: You mean in the app? I used mysite.com, but maybe I need to add /administrator or something? mysite.com is a basic joomla website with no Civicrm content on the frontpage only on backend. So the question is what is does a civicrm website url should look like, I guess. So weird that it did work before:-O, Now I don't remember if I put in another url or not.